# Wordpress create front end page from plug in

Tags: wordpress, frontend, backend, permalinks

I've to create a plugin that from back-end could create a page in front-end.
I need to know the code to create this front-end page and his permalink when from back-end they click "Create page"! Like "Ignitiondeck" does, for example.
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

**A very simple example to create a page:**

```
$args = array(
    'post_title' => 'My new page',
    'post_type' => 'page',  
);

wp_insert_post( $args );
```

For more information read the [Code Reference for `wp_insert_post()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/).

Comment: I don't need to do a post, I need a page with wordpress template but with my disposition!